# how to display box on same page when a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, php

I am making php based web application .I'd like to have a box displayed on the same page when a link is being clicked using java script.How can i achieve this??
I have tried the below code

```
<script>
function a()
{
    document.getElementsById("a").style.visibility="visible";
}
</script>

<a style="position:absolute;left:84%;top:32%;font-size:13px " href="" onclick="a()">
    Forgot Password?
</a>

<div id="a" style="position:absolute;left:30%;top:10%;width:40%;height:40%;background-color:lightgray;visibility:hidden">
</div>
```

Comment: You mean like a pop-up "lightbox" ?

Comment: am not familiar with query.please check flipkart application signup link.I need such a display box when link is being clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You needed to fix `getElementsById` isn't plural, should be `getElementById`

To stop the page reloading on click, set `href="javascript:a()"`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<script>
function a()
{
    document.getElementById("a").style.visibility="visible";
}
function close_a()
{
    document.getElementById("a").style.visibility="hidden";
}
</script>

<a style="position:absolute;left:84%;top:32%;font-size:13px " href="javascript:a()">
    Forgot Password?
</a>

<div id="a" style="position:absolute;left:30%;top:10%;width:40%;height:40%;background-color:lightgray;visibility:hidden">
<a href="javascript:close_a()"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i> Close Me</a>
</div>
```

added function to close and [font awesome](http://fontawesome.io/)

Comment: Thankyou..got it..now how to close that display box

Comment: I'm sure you could have figured it out, but I updated my answer with a close function.

Comment: i need close icon on the top of the box..how can i acheve this

Comment: I would suggest using [font awesome](http://fontawesome.io/) because they are, well, awesome. I have updated my answer with an example.

Comment: actually i dont want close me text..only close icon..please check flipkart app (go to sell link and then to forgot password link)..i need same as that.what change should i make to this code??

Answer (score 1):

The method of document is wrong.

It should be `getElementById`, you could use Google chrome DEV tools (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> on windows, <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> on Mac) to debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this and the box will be displayed:

```
<script>
function a()
{
    document.getElementById("a").style.display="block";
    return false;
}
</script>

<a style="position:absolute;left:84%;top:32%;font-size:13px " href="#" onclick="return a()">
    Forgot Password?
</a>

<div id="a" style="position:absolute;left:30%;top:10%;width:40%;height:40%;background-color:lightgray;display: none">
</div>
```

There was an error in your code. `getElementById` is correct, and your `<a>` link refresh the page, correct method to avoid refresh is to change `onclick="a();"` to `onclick="return a();"` so that javascript look for return of function, and in function, we return false, therefore keep page same and avoid refresh.

Additionally you can add content to your box:

```
<script>
function a()
{

    document.getElementById("a").style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("a").innerHTML="<b>your other contents inside the box</b>";
    return false;
}
</script>

<a style="position:absolute;left:84%;top:32%;font-size:13px " href="#" onclick="return a();">
    Forgot Password?
</a>

<div id="a" style="position:absolute;left:30%;top:10%;width:40%;height:40%;background-color:lightgray;display: none">
</div>
```